# IdentityServer3 with WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: win-universal-app, identityserver3

Has anyone used IdentityServer3 with WebAuthenticationBroker to implement  SSO in windows universal app (WUP)?

For some reason the broker class decides to POST! to the STS at some point and it does not see the correct redirect (in the form of ms-app://sid#tokens) that is coming from STS.

I can see in the fiddler traces that STS is indeed redirecting to the proper location in the last step:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 0
Location: ms-app://s-1-15-2-38.../#code=0bdb86...&id_token=eyJ0eX...&access_token=eyJ0e...&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=7776000&scope=openid%20offline_access%20email&state=xyz&session_state=367wnzhjdQ2r9TiX7sZmQ03y_kjBMKNVVwr6xfuByQ0.cd1e1d29ed153a7b4743bd0f51def6a3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here (IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples):
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/Uwp/UwpSample